# 10 month old large breed crate time

Tags: dogs, containment, exercise

My puppy is rather large for his age. He sleeps out of his crate at night, is up at 9 am, put in the crate at around 2:30 pm for me to go to school, let out of the cage at 9pm when I get back. That's six of his waking hours a day spent in the crate. I take him for about a thirty minute walk every morning unless it's downpouring and on weekends I take him to the park sometimes twice a weekend for an hour or so and he gets high energy exercise.

My room mates say I neglect him. This may be because when I go to school they are just getting home from work and he is in the crate until I get back. But sometimes they really make me feel terrible about it and I don't know if maybe I am neglecting him.

This is what my parents did with our dogs and I thought everyone else did too. Once he can handle being out of his crate with the upstairs neighbors home I'll let him roam around all day, but as of now he can't handle more than two hours out and about and that's only if no one is upstairs to make noise. idk.

Comment: Could you explain why your dog "can't handle more than two hours out and about and that's only if no one is upstairs to make noise"? The underlying problem here seems to be the noise from your neighbours, not keeping your dog in a crate for so long.

Comment: Can your room mates not let him out while they're at home?

Comment: Welcome! Can I ask what breed is the dog?

Comment: Also why is it you feel the need to keep it in a crate? How or why does that make a difference with the neighbours?